# Estimated hardware cost to crack ARGON2ID hashed passwords

Tags: password-hashing, argon2

I can find a bunch of information on stuff like bcrypt and script, but I am interested in estimating the cost per hash on something like Argon2id that is GPU hardened.  I am trying to do the best with what I have here. The requirement is that the user is given an 8 letter password that I can generate.

My strategy is to use the human-facing password to use generate a secret key for a libsodium crypto_secretbox_easy.  I know this is not ideal, so I am operating under the assumption that as soon as the message is stored someone will attack it.  While not sensitive I just want to make it annoying enough to keep the normal baddies out.  (ie, not the NSA)  Knowing that I want to make sure I can at least pick something that will make it cost-prohibitive for someone to just download a bunch of these and start cracking the messages. So is there a way to estimate the cost to generate enough hashes to get access to the contents?